# Ceph Rados : Facing errors during dependencies installation on Ubuntu

Tags: package, storage, ubuntu-20.04, ceph, radosgw

I am getting few errors during dependencies installation step in the **install-deps.sh** script.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-atomic1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-atomic1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-atomic1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-chrono1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-chrono1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-chrono1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-container1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-container1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-container1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-context1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-context1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-context1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-coroutine1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-coroutine1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-coroutine1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-date-time1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-date-time1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-date-time1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-filesystem1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-filesystem1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-filesystem1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-iostreams1.79-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ceph-libboost-iostreams1.79-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ceph-libboost-iostreams1.79-dev'
E: Unable to locate package ceph-libboost-program-options1.79-dev
```

I've tried to run apt-get update and then run apt-get install -f But the error still there. Also, I tried to install dependencies using **ubuntu aptitude**, but still no luck.

Few inputs are required here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of debugging, I have found that above errors are resolved after updating the ca-certificates. Please find the command below:

> sudo update-ca-certificates